# Continuous distributed SMTP auth requests for a non-existent user - any idea what the purpose is?

Tags: security, smtp, port-scanning

I have thousands of SMTP auth requests for the same non-existent user, from IP addresses mostly in Argentina. There is rarely more than one hit per IP.

The login will never work because it's not a valid user, but I'm baffled what the purpose is.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: `I'm baffled what the purpose is` My guess is that they're trying to compromise your email server and potentially other systems of yours.

Comment: There's at least one really dumb SMTP password guesser active. I've had one hitting my server for a while that just connects, sends an AUTH command, gets rejected 'cause I don't allow that without STARTTLS first, disconnects... then connects again a few minutes later to try again. I don't even know what username it wants to try. Mine's mostly coming from Russia, though.

Comment: @joeqwerty What would the compromise be? The attempt will never succeed and the rate isn't fast enough to be any sort of detectable load.